# Properly associate Key / Value Pairs

Tags: arrays, node.js, https, axios

I've been trying to figure this out but still having trouble. I have an array of objects and what I am trying to do is update the key of slug to ID and change it's value to the ID of the blog post that is returned from an API. I also want to do the same for the key featuredImage where I return data from API and then update the value in this array of objects. I don't have anyway to associate the slug to the featuredImage except for the way they appears in the original postData array of objects. If I am going to be making API calls and also manipulating the data is there a way to ensure that I don't mess up my key / value pairs here. What I've been struggling with is I can't seem to hold the order properly and my data ends up being in the wrong order in my final array of objects. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
const postData =[
{ slug: sample-post-1, featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/rustic20coffee20table.jpeg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' },
{ slug: sample-post-2, featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/Amazing-Table-For-Flamboyant-Furniture-Home-Design-Ideas-With-Rustic-Furniture-Coffee-Table.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' },
{ slug: sample-post-3, featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/envoy-lookout-rooftop-11b-780x520.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg'  },
{ slug: sample-post-4, featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/mountain-landscape-wallpaper-29048-29765-hd-wallpapers.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg'},
{ slug: sample-post-5, featuredImage: 'https://www.rusticfurnitureboston.com/hubfs/Blog_Media/mountain-landscape-wallpaper-29048-29765-hd-wallpapers.jpg%3Ft=1528912781831-6.jpeg' }
]
```

This is the function that I am trying to run but this is where I try to create a new Object based on the response the items are out of order.

```
const uploadImages = async (postData) => {
  const newImages = [];
    try {
     await Promise.all(postData.map(async featuredImage => {
       const option = {
       method: 'POST',
       url: fileAPIURL,
       qs: {
        access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
       },
       headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
       },
       formData: {
         folder_paths: 'Blog_Media',
         image: request(featuredImage)
       },
       json: true
    }
    return request(option)
      .then((response) => {
        response.objects.map((content) => {
          return newImages.push(Object.assign({ 
            featuredImage:content.url }));
          });
        })
     }))
     return newImages;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Cannot upload image to file manager, try checking 
    your URL');
  }  
}
```

Comment: Having trouble understanding what your're asking here.  You say "update the key of slug to ID".  What does that mean?  Do you mean "update the value of the slug property on one of the items in the array"?  If so, what is the problem you're having with updating that propery?  What do you mean with "is there a way to ensure that I don't mess up my key / value pairs here"?  What's the problem with holding the order.  As long as you don't remove items from the array, they won't change their order.

Comment: For example what I see on my end is I have the featuredImages in one specific order and then when I hit the api passing in the featuredImage within the response of the API when I look at the new URL that is being returned they are out of order due to the async behavior of JS. Not sure if I should try and return the response synchronously or if theres a better way to match up the key / value pairs so that even if the API return a response out of order the logic will know where to update the value of the featuredImage.

Comment: Well, then there's something wrong with your async code.  You will have to show that code to us for us to offer a fix.

Comment: I've added the function that I am running on the data. When I push the new returned data into the array that I created this is when I get items out of order. I thought that I would create two separate array of objects and then merge them together when I have the other response from another function that I am running to return data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a bunch of asynchronous operations in parallel, they can complete it any order.  So, when you do this:

```
newImages.push(...)
```

The newImages array is going to be in the order that your parallel async operations were completed.  That will be some random order.

But, `Promise.all()` will keep the data in the proper order if you let it manage the returned data for you.  So, inside of `postData.map()`, you can return an array of objects.  Then `Promise.all()` will keep that array in the proper order relative to the other arrays.  Then, at the end of the `Promise.all().then()`, you will have an array of arrays (all in the proper order) so all you need to do to get it into a single flat array in the proper order is to flatten that.

```
const uploadImages = (postData) => {
    return Promise.all(postData.map(featuredImage => {
        const option = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: fileAPIURL,
            qs: {
                access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
            },
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            formData: {
                folder_paths: 'Blog_Media',
                image: request(featuredImage)
            },
            json: true
        }
        return request(option).then((response) => {
            return response.objects.map((content) => {
                return {featuredImage: content.url};
            });
        });
    })).then(results => {
        // flatten the array of arrays into a single array
        return [].concat.apply([], results);
    }).catch(error => {
        throw new Error('Cannot upload image to file manager, try checking your URL ');
    });
}
```

Also, you don't seem to be actually using async/await for anything useful here to I removed that.

---

The one part of your code I don't understand is where you pass:

```
image: request(featuredImage)
```

as part of the `formData` to another request.  That will put a promise into the `formData` since `request(featuredImage)` will return a promise.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: Thats actually really helpful. I hadn't considered to keep chaining on to return the results thank you! What I was trying to do there was I have a URL of an image and I was trying to was make a request to the URL of the image to add that to the form data. I was looking through examples that showed using the request module in this way to return the data from an image url. Is there potentially a better solution?

Comment: @JamesZilch - What are you trying to send for that image in the `formData`?  The actual binary image data?  Or a URL of an image?

Comment: I was trying to send the actual binary image data. Before what I was doing if saving the image locally on my computer and then using the node file system to create a read stream and use that as the value. All I was trying to do was to pass the data of the image directly instead of saving the image locally.  It didn't seem like form data would just accept a URL of an image as I passed it in. I had originally found this solution from form-data npm package

Comment: @JamesZilch - Maybe it works as it is because in addition to returning a promise, the return value is also a stream which the `request()` library does support in formData.  Anyway, did my answer provide an answer to your original question?

Comment: Yes, Thanks you so much! I just tested this on my end and I am seeing everything working as I originally expected.

Comment: Is there a way with the above code that I added that I can add back in async / await and make sure all of this above code is resolved before moving on. I am using async/ await but I am getting undefined because that object with content.url isn't created yet and the code keeps moving on

Comment: @JamesZilch - No, you can't.  `uploadImages()` is asynchronous and returns a promise in either my version or any `async/await` version.  The caller of `uploadImages()` needs to either use `.then()` or `await` on the return value from `uploadImages()` to know when it's done.  If you want to show the calling code (where this issue would be addressed) in a new question, you can post a new question that shows that.  Remember, ALL `async` functions return a promise.  Javascript does not "block" and wait for an `async` function to finish before returning.  That's not how `async/await` works.